# Github docker package registry manifest pulling issue

Tags: docker, jenkins, registry, manifest, deprecated

After upgrading to the latest docker version (20.10.6) when I'm trying to pull a docker image from my GitHub docker package registry I'm getting the following warning:

```
 
Failed to pull manifest by the resolved digest. This registry does not
    appear to conform to the distribution registry specification; falling back to
    pull by tag.  This fallback is DEPRECATED, and will be removed in a future
    release.  Please contact admins of https://docker.pkg.github.com.
```

This causes also failing my jenkins build with the following error:

```
 load metadata for docker.pkg.github.com/image
#3 sha256:b2f3809e632a5c2307f76aef7ef31915a322aa04264d95f989a9b7fb1e0d8aff
#3 ERROR: failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: content at https://docker.pkg.github.com/v2//manifests/sha256:0aab8488953c2f481817daf2026170105ce4c7234e2703bc8c98cbeba896c66c not found: not found
```

Can anybody help me if there is a setting on the github registry level or what could be the problem?